# Should versions of java & javac be same in the system?

Tags: java, version, javac

Should java & javac version be same in the system?
as I am having `java -version`

> java version "1.8.0_251" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
>   1.8.0_251-b08) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.251-b08, mixed mode)

and `javac -version`

> javac 1.8.0_181

Is there any issue if it's not the same version?

Comment: Yes, ideally they should, but as long as both are 1.8.0 the difference probably won't have a noticeable effect for you.

Answer (score 0):

> Should java & javac version be same in the system?

Not really, you can have as many java version as you want on one system, as long as you know which version you use when compiling or running application. If you have multiple java version in your system, be aware which version you put on your **PATH** environment variable to avoid a miss.

Your problem should be caused by multiple entry in your **PATH** environment variable that refering to java installation directory that has different version (note, `java` can be found in JDK and JRE installation, while `javac` can only be found in JDK installation).

> Is there any issue if it's not the same version?

There should be no issue, as long as you don't use features that can only be found on the java version you use when compiling the program. In your case, the different is in build version, it's okay.

Comment: Consider to use absolute path when invoking java/javac, to ensure which java version you want to run.